# How can I avoid an administrator from editing IIS default website properties

Tags: windows, iis, administration

We are a big team. some of us having admin access on development servers that host development version of products.

Is it possible to still limit who can access a certain virtual directory or Default websites properties from IIS.

Ex: I want person A to be able to control settings of his application on IIS but not the default website or someone else's application controlled in the same IIS.

Comment: possible duplicate:http://serverfault.com/questions/122813/access-iis-admin-without-local-administrator-rights

Answer (score 0):

If they are a local administrator then you won't be able to stop them doing *anything*.

If they are not a local administrator then you can give them permissions to edit individual virtual directories or the entire web site by editing the permissions for that directory in `inetmgr` (IIS Manager).  In IIS 7 do this by right clicking on the directory in IIS Manager and selecting "Edit Permissions...".

Comment: They are in administrators group on the machine.. we can remove that.. but how will they even open IIS to control their virtual directory/application settings if they are not admins ?